# Composer hidden Token

Tags: php, windows, github, composer-php

Everytime I update composer I have to enter a Token generated on github.
I use [this plugin](https://github.com/francoispluchino/composer-asset-plugin) to install bower packages.

This happened after github.com/RamonSmit/Nestable.git became a private repo.
I removed all references to this repo.

But I still get the message:

> Your GitHub credentials are required to fetch private repository metadata (git://github.com/RamonSmit/Nestable.git)
>
> Head to https://github.com/settings/tokens/new?scopes=repo&description=...
>   to retrieve a token. It will be stored in "..." for future use by Composer.
>   Token (hidden):

I updated composer and composer-asset-plugin to the latest version and cleared the cache.

This also didn't work:

```
composer config --global github-oauth.github.com xxx
```

How can I get rid of this unnecessary message?

Output of `composer diag`:

```
Checking composer.json: FAIL
require.yiisoft/yii2 : unbound version constraints (>=2.0.6) should be avoided
require.yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap : unbound version constraints (*) should be avoided
require.yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer : unbound version constraints (*) should be avoided
require.fishvision/yii2-migrate : unbound version constraints (*) should be avoided
require.infoweb-internet-solutions/yii2-cms : unbound version constraints (*) should be avoided
require.bower-asset/matchHeight : unbound version constraints (@stable) should be avoided
require.infoweb-internet-solutions/yii2-news : unbound version constraints (*) should be avoided
require.infoweb-internet-solutions/yii2-action : unbound version constraints (*) should be avoided
require.infoweb-internet-solutions/yii2-member : unbound version constraints (*) should be avoided
require.dragonjet/yii2-opengraph : unbound version constraints (*) should be avoided
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking https connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking github.com oauth access: OK
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking pubkeys:
Tags Public Key Fingerprint: xxx
Dev Public Key Fingerprint: xxx
OK
Checking composer version: OK
```

`auth.json`: (located in C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Composer)

```
{
    "github-oauth": {
        "github.com": "xxx"
    },
    "http-basic": {
        "bitbucket.org": {
            "username": "xxx",
            "password": "xxx"
        }
    }
}
```

`composer global show -i`

```
Changed current directory to C:/Users/Ruben/AppData/Roaming/Composer
fxp/composer-asset-plugin v1.1.1 NPM/Bower Dependency Manager for Composer
```

composer.json:

```
{
  "name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced",
  "description": "Yii 2 Advanced Project Template",
  "keywords": [
    "yii2",
    "framework",
    "advanced",
    "project template"
  ],
  "homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
  "type": "project",
  "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
  "support": {
    "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
    "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
    "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
    "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
    "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
  },
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2": ">=2.0.6",
    "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "*",
    "fishvision/yii2-migrate": "*",
    "infoweb-internet-solutions/yii2-cms": "*",
    "bower-asset/matchHeight": "@stable",
    "infoweb-internet-solutions/yii2-news": "*",
    "infoweb-internet-solutions/yii2-action": "*",
    "infoweb-internet-solutions/yii2-member": "*",
    "dragonjet/yii2-opengraph": "*",
    "infoweb-internet-solutions/yii2-image-gallery": "*"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "yiisoft/yii2-codeception": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "*"
  },
  "config": {
    "process-timeout": 1800,
    "preferred-install": "source"
  },
  "extra": {
    "asset-installer-paths": {
      "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
      "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
    }
  },
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "https://github.com/infoweb-internet-solutions/yii2-i18n-module"
    },
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "https://github.com/infoweb-internet-solutions/yii2-ckeditor"
    },
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "git@bitbucket.org:infoweb-internet-solutions/yii2-news.git"
    },
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "git@bitbucket.org:infoweb-internet-solutions/yii2-action.git"
    },
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "git@bitbucket-infoweb:infoweb-internet-solutions/yii2-member.git"
    }
  ]
}
```

[composer.lock](https://gist.github.com/rubenheymans/08ab6f1d56d810c10b60)

Comment: Did you check `composer.lock` file?

Comment: yes, I already removed `composer.lock` and after running `composer update` again I can't find Nestable in there

Comment: maybe this is a bug and I should open an issue on github?

Comment: Did you remove your vendor folder and reinstall all packages?

Comment: Please run a `composer self-update` and attach the output of `composer diag` to your question. Its strange that `config --global` didn't work out. Try to locate `auth.json` in your `COMPOSER_HOME` folder and check its content. It seems that the Nestable dependency is still in there somewhere.. is it globally installed? If yes, delete it.

Comment: I updated my question, did not find a solution

Comment: composer and fxp/composer-asset-plugin are the latest versions

Comment: Does this happen to every Composer project or only to the one where Nestable was used before? Just trying to figure out if it is a global Composer issue or a project based issue.

Comment: Only to the one where Nestable was used before. If I create a new yii project it doens't ask for the token. But it does ask for the token when I add our  cms project (https://github.com/infoweb-internet-solutions/yii2-cms)

Comment: @Ruben show output of  `grep -rni RamonSmit composer.{json,lock}`

Comment: @RamilAmr it does not return anything

Comment: @Ruben could you show `composer.json` and `composer.lock` here?

Comment: I just created a new project with my custom cms and it's asking for the token, but there's no reference in my code to the Nestable package

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should generate new tokens on github

```
Settings \ Developer settings \ Personal access tokens
```

Answer (score 5):

Note the token can also [be added](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#github-oauth) manually to the `composer.json` file:

```
{
    "require": {
        "infoweb-internet-solutions/yii2-action": "*",
    },
    "config": {
        "github-oauth": {
            "github.com": "your long token"
        }
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@bitbucket.org:infoweb-internet-solutions/yii2-action.git"
        },
    ]
}
```

---

However, if you're committing the file to a VCS repository, you may not want to include the credentials in the file. In that case, you can use the [`COMPOSER_AUTH` environment variable](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-auth) to pass the same information.

```sh
export COMPOSER_AUTH='{"github-oauth":{"github.com": "your long token"}}'
composer update
```

Comment: Github discourages checking in secrets and may in the future disable discovered keys. https://github.blog/2021-03-30-github-advanced-security-security-overview-beta-secret-scanning-private-repos/

Answer (score -3):

Delete `composer.lock` file.

Then delete the vendor folder and run composer again to install all the packages.